# ImageView does not work more than once

Tags: java, android, imageview, drawable

i have 9 ImageViews in my XML.

declared ImageView in the class:

```
ImageView image;
```

a little bit about the code:
it's a tic tac toe game, user vs smartphone, when I the user click on any ImageView the image changes fine to the image i want thru the onClick(View v) function using:

```
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block2);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.block_2_x);
```

after my turn ends, the smartphone is playing , using same two lines but with different  ID and DRAWABLE .
calling another function named `computerPlay() { ... }`

then nothing happens but errors.

BUT, when i run the app again and the smarthphone starts first, the image changes fine in the `computerPlay() { .. }`

and then my turn gets the errors...

somehow, i feel it's because i can not use the same ImageView more than once ?

---

big picture of the code:
(WHEN USER CLICK ON IMAGE)

```
public void touch(View v) {

    ........
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block1);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.block_1_x);
.......
}
```

WHEN COMPUTER TRIES TO PLAY:

```
public void changeImage() {
...
                    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block2);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.block_1_o);
...
}
```

ANY IDEAS?

---

errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Widget has the wrong parent
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setMenu(Control.java:3462)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel$20.handleEvent(LogCatPanel.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.showMenu(Widget.java:1472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmContextMenu(Widget.java:1574)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CONTEXTMENU(Control.java:4673)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.WM_CONTEXTMENU(Table.java:5972)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4532)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5913)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmRButtonUp(Widget.java:2395)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_RBUTTONUP(Control.java:5134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5913)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Logcat:

```
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): Process: com.example.tttgame, PID: 1377
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6006)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:822)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16392)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:370)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.example.tttgame.BoardActivity.changeImage(BoardActivity.java:755)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.example.tttgame.BoardActivity.fillboard(BoardActivity.java:739)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.example.tttgame.BoardActivity.randPick(BoardActivity.java:715)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.example.tttgame.BoardActivity.computerPlay(BoardActivity.java:525)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.example.tttgame.BoardActivity$7.run(BoardActivity.java:387)
05-18 23:43:25.760: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: "nothing happens but errors" -- and the errors are? Where's your logcat?

Comment: i added two pictures of the errors ..

Comment: Copy/paste your logcat. Don't post pictures on porn sites.

Comment: Thank you -- with the logcat added, Lawrence Choy, below, was able to answer you in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are running the computer play code inside a `TimerTask`. It is not run on the UI thread, thus throws the error you saw when you are trying to modify the views.

Inside your `TimerTask`, use the follow code to wrap your existing codes:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This will run on the UI thread
            changeImage();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot, 
does this apply for all Views when i use TIMER ?? like changing colors of textview and etc.. ?

Comment: @user3651124 Yes, whenever you want to manipulate a view, that code needs to be run on UI thread.